# Setting edit page as default in Route Config for development triggers HTTPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently developing Edit page for one of the models, so I've set Edit page as default in Route Config. Problem is, that for some reason it's triggering Post event instead of Get. Example is very simple:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    JobLine jobLine = db.JobLines.Find(id);

    if (jobLine == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    Mapper.CreateMap<JobLine, JobLineDTO>();
    JobLineDTO joblineDTO = Mapper.Map<JobLine, JobLineDTO>(jobLine);

    return View("Create",joblineDTO);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(JobLineDTO jobLineDTO)
{
    return View();
}
```

What could possibly be a reason for such behavior?

Route Config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Joblines", action = "Edit", id = 1 /*UrlParameter.Optional*/ }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the default route? Also your form that you make the edit? (only the `Html.BeginForm .... `)

Comment: Form is way too large, so here is the beginning and the end:
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="msls-absolute-buttons">
        <span class="msls-absolute-span tooltip-top" data-tooltip="Save Changes">
            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="msls-absolute-button msls-save btn btn-success"></button>
        </span>
    </div>
}

Comment: Everything looks good on this. How you try to access the `Edit` Action?

Comment: I replicated your code in a sample project and it is working as expected. Check if there are any redirections in any other part of the code.

Comment: There aren't any redirects. I've recreated it myself in a new project and everything seems to work. I really don't understand..